# Re aligning child controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-controls

I am overriding DisplayRectangle property of my custom control;

```
public override Rectangle DisplayRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            Rectangle rect = ThemeSupporter.GetInnerFrameRect();
            rect.X += Padding.Left;
            rect.Y += Padding.Top;
            rect.Width -= Padding.Left + Padding.Right;
            rect.Height -= Padding.Top + Padding.Bottom;
            return rect;
        }
    }
```

So frame of my custom control effects child control's docking. I want to realign my child controls every time i make a change on frame of my control. But i could not find a single method to do that. I want something like this :

```
public FrameX Frame
{
  get { return FFrameX; }
  set { FFrameX = value; RealignChildControls(); }
}
```

instead, i resize my control like this

```
public void ControlResize()
    {
        Control control = GetControl();
        Rectangle oldB = control.Bounds;
        control.SetBounds(oldB.X + 1, oldB.Y + 1, oldB.Width - 1, oldB.Height - 1);
        control.SetBounds(oldB.X, oldB.Y, oldB.Width, oldB.Height);
    }
```

this causes of course extra flickrings and slowness.. so is there some method like RealignChildControls() ?

Answer (score 0):

i found it

```
control.PerformLayout();
```

this realigns child controls